# TStrings is returned as "Inaccessible value" when exception is raised in function

Tags: delphi

Could somebody help me explain why the TStrings is returned as "Inaccessible value" when an exception is raised in the underlyning function?

```
function GetStrings():TStrings;
begin
  result := TStringList.Create;
  try
    raise exception.Create('Error Message');
  except
    FreeAndNil(result);
    raise
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S : TStrings;
begin
  try
    S := GetStrings;
    try
      //Do awesome stuff
    finally
      FreeAndNil(S)
    end;
  except
    //Debug watch: S = "Inaccessible value"
    Assert(S = nil, 'Assertion failure, S should be nil'); 
  end;
end;
```

The function `GetStrings` also returns "Inaccessible value" if I don't call `FreeAndNil(result);` prior to reraising the exception. However, then I have a memory leak on my hands aswell :-O

Comment: +1 Very good question, well asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
try
  S := GetStrings; 
  try
    //Do awesome stuff
  finally
    FreeAndNil(S)
  end;
except
  //Debug watch: S = "Inaccessible value"
  Assert(S = nil, 'Assertion failure, S should be nil'); 
end;
```

Here is the sequence of execution:

1. Since `S` is a local variable, its value is indeterminate until is has been initialized. That is the state as this code begins execution.
2. The `GetStrings` function is called.
3. An exception is raised in `GetStrings`. Which means that `GetStrings` does not return execution to the caller and so has the consequence that `S` is never assigned.
4. The `finally` block does not execute because its try was never reached.
5. Next, the `except` block executes, and `S` has indeterminate value, which is what you have observed.

In fact, the compiler should warn (W1036) that `S` might not have been initialized when you refer to it in the `except` block. But it doesn't seem to be able to do that, which is rather pathetic.

If you wish to be able to refer to `S` in your `except` block, you will need to nest it inside the `try/finally`.

```
S := GetStrings; 
try
  try
    //Do awesome stuff
  except
    //Do stuff with S
    Assert(S <> nil);
  end;
finally
  FreeAndNil(S)
end;
```

Another way of thinking about this is that `S` is only meaningful in between the code that assigns to `S`, and the code that destroys the object. The consequence being that the `try/except` must be nested inside the `try/finally`, if the `except` block is going to be able to refer to the object.

Comment: can you put S:= nil; try S := GetStrings; ??

Comment: @Passella You could do that. I wouldn't.

Comment: I was debugging some code recently in XE5 and discovered that although I assigned a valid value to a Result in a function, an exception that was raised shortly afterwards seemed to prevent the value from being returned, as the result coming back from the function was random garbage (and, no, it was not the object that caused the exception). In this case, I'd expect GetStrings() to return NIL, not a valid pointer to a TStringList, simply because the except clause calls FreeAndNil(Result) before the function exits.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Your understanding is off. When a function throws an exception, no value is returned. When you write `x = foo();` and `foo()` throws, then no value is assigned to `x`.

Comment: So how can your statement above, "that S is only meaningful in between the code that assigns to S, and the code that destroys the object" be valid if no value is assigned to it as a result of an exception being thrown within GetStrings()?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If an exception is raised in `GetStrings` then S is never valid. The code that exists between the assignment to S and the destruction of S will not execute.

Comment: If that's true, then why do you say this: "Another way of thinking about this is that S is only meaningful in between the code that assigns to S, and the code that destroys the object." ??? Anyway, I'm talking about code within GetStrings(), while you're talking about code in the outer scope that called it.

Comment: Everything I have said in the answer and comments concerns the code outside GetStrings.

Comment: And as for why I made that comment that you keep referring to, it is surely beyond argument that `S` is not meaningful until it has been assigned a valid value. And ceases to be meaningful when the object to which it refers is destroyed. You cannot disagree with that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, `Result` is a local variable in the context of the function it appears in. Generally speaking, it's *not* an alias for the variable the function's result is assigned to upon return. (Such a variable needn't necessarily exist!) Assigning to `Result` in `GetStrings` does not immediately modify `S` in the caller. Rather, `S` is only assigned after `GetStrings` returns. *If `GetStrings` throws, then it does not return*, and so `S` doesn't get assigned in that case.

Comment: Many thanks David Heffernan for your comprehensive answer! It was the information You provided in bullet #3 that I was primarily out to get.  Thank You Rob Kennedy for your input too!